# Possible to Determine ALL User Accounts In Windows 7 With VBS?

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

I would like to get all user accounts and associated groups on a Windows 7 machine listed in "User Accounts" (see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVps1.jpg).

[image: nVps1.jpg]

You can click <kbd>Add...</kbd> and add any domain account.  Note that these added accounts do NOT appear in the Local User Manager (`lusrmgr.msc`).

When querying WMI like such `"Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True"` the account **CORP\jon** is NOT returned.  I suspect that the attached screenshot is more likely a list of allowed credentials than actual accounts.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get these with a .VBS script?  Thank you!

PS: If for some reason the image link dies then you can get to the "User Accounts" section by running the following: `netplwiz.exe`.

Comment: What does the `Select` you mentioned return if you leave out the `Where LocalAccount = true` condition?

Comment: I tried that and it returns all domain accounts.  I'm starting to think that what I'm looking for isn't technically a user account at all so this query might not be able to access the information I want.

Comment: Also, a big clue is the process NetplWiz, which I just discovered.

Comment: There are a few account objects in WMI. Win32_Account, Win32_Group, Win32_GroupInDomain, Win32_GroupUser, Win32_SystemAccount, Win32_SystemUsers, and  Win32_UserAccount.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after some digging.  Administrator users reported using netplwiz.exe are actually added to the machine's local Administrator's group (so **lusrmgr.msc** after all!).  For the above example, you can echo out all of the Administrator users in the machine's local Administrators group in the domain "CORP" with the following code:

```
Set objWinNT = GetObject("WinNT://./Administrators,group") ' get members of the local admin group
For Each item In objWinNT.Members
    strDomain = mid(item.Parent, 9) ' truncate domain name

    ' If TRUE, we have a domain Administrator account added to the local Administrators group
    If strDomain = "CORP" Then
        Wscript.Echo strDomain & "\" & item.Name
    End If

Next
```

I hope this helps someone!